# terminal command to scan for nearby mac addresses

Tags: macos, networking, ip, wifi, ip-address

Is there a terminal command line [on OS X] for scanning nearby mac addresses? Not the `airport` that lists the SSIDs of nearby routers, but something to list the devices [like phones].

I want to use it to run a cron and run a script every time a specific device comes into range.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could clarify if you were hoping for the command to find devices which are present but not connected to your network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking only about Wi-Fi protocol ([802.11n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n)) there is no way for a STA to find the others STAs. A STA can only scan for APs.

But there is a new Wi-Fi protocol called [Wi-Fi Direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) in which you can search for PEERs. In this case, the other devices needs to have Wi-Fi Direct enabled ...

If you want to use only the "default" Wi-Fi, you can sniff all [channels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels) and check for [probe request frames](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/print.php/1447501). But it's not straightforward.

**Note:** *I assume that we are only in "infrastructure mode" cause the "[ad-hoc mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network)" is not very used*

Answer (score 13):

Have a try with the following:

```
arp -a
```

Sample output:

```
router.asus.com (192.168.0.1) at 8:60:6e:ba:17:c8 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
vmubuntu (192.168.0.9) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.225) at 0:a0:96:c7:8a:c1 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

Comment: This can be used only if you are connected to a Wi-Fi network. Moreover, the only STAs that you can find this way are those which are also connected to the same network.

Comment: This works on my Mac which is not connected to a wifi network, and the router (router.asus.com) is connected by cable. And anyway, the OP must clearly mean wifi devices because he refers to airport and also mentions phones which are always wifi, insofar as they don't generally have Ethernet connectors. Maybe you could clarify/check please as you are clearly knowledgeable about wifi, thanks.

Comment: this is not the most reliable and will return any ip address you recently attempted to ssh into or ping'd

Answer (score 2):

There is a product I use on my iPhone, and there is apparently also an OSX version. It's called "fing" and it scans your network and tells you the MAC addresses of attached devices - it can also send Wake-on-LAN packets - which is what I use it for.

See Fing [here](http://www.overlooksoft.com/fing).

**Note**: I wouldn't normally recommend 3rd party paid apps (see my other answer in which I suggested "arp"), and I have no connection with these guys and derive nothing from mentioning them - I just feel their product may help you out.